# C++ How to convert an unsigned integer to a hex string without a thousands separator

Tags: c++, string, formatting, integer, hex

To store the color of a button's text, I have the variable `uint32_t textColor` set to the value 0xF5CE52 (0d16109138). Now I need to insert this value of textColor into a string as a hexadecimal value. However, when I try to convert textColor to a hex string via a stringstream, it seems like a thousands separator is inserted in the hex string and I can't figure out how to prevent this from happening...

To convert textColor to a hexadecimal string, I'm using the following piece of code:

```
uint32_t textColor = 0xF5CE52;
stringstream btnColorHex;
btnColorHex << uppercase << setfill('0') << setw(6) << hex << textColor;
```

I print it using the following:

```
cout << "btnColorHex.str() - " << btnColorHex.str() << endl;
```

Which results in the following output:

```
btnColorHex.str() - F5C.E52
```

*Note: I have set my system locales to format numbers in Dutch formatting, which uses . as the thousands separator and , as the decimal separator.*

I expected the following to be printed to the console:

```
btnColorHex.str() - F5CE52
```

I had 'solved' this issue by removing the . from the string afterwards, but of course this didn't work when I tested this code on a PC with the locales set to American formatting using , as the thousands separator.

I have also tried casting the `uint32_t` to an `unsgined int`, but that resulted in the same issues.

I could try using functions like `sprintf()` from plain C to circumvent this issue, but I'd like to now if there is a proper C++ way to do this first.

So my question is: Is there a way in C++ to format an unsigned integer as a hex string, without it inserting a thousands separator?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the use of the locale in your app? try `btnColorHex.imbue(std::locale("C"));`

Comment: Since C++11 `std::sprintf` is part of the C++ standard. [Link cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). That said, I would use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: I have *never* seen `std::hex` output a thousands separator, even if one is defined in the system locale. Printing a hex number using `operator<<` will ultimately just call `...printf()` internally using `"%x"` or `%X`, per [`std::num_put::put()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the locale formating use `imbue(std::locale("C"))`

Your code will now look like this:

```
uint32_t textColor = 0xF5CE52;
stringstream btnColorHex;
btnColorHex.imbue(std::locale("C"));
btnColorHex << uppercase << setfill('0') << setw(6) << hex << textColor;
```

Now regardless of the PC's locale the output will always be formatted correctly:

```
btnColorHex.str() - F5CE52
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just handwrite this as

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

std::string hex( uint32_t value ) {
    char str[16];
    char* p = &str[16];
    do {
        p--;
        uint32_t digit = value % 16; 
        value /= 16;
        *p = digit>=10 ? 'a' + (digit-10) : '0' + digit;
    } while ( value > 0 );
    p--;
    *p = 'x';
    p--;
    *p = '0';
    return std::string(p,&str[16]-p);
}
```

Running as

```cpp
int main()
{
    for ( int j=0; j<10; ++j ) {
        uint32_t value = std::rand();
        std::cout << std::hex << value << " " << hex( value ) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Produces

```
6b8b4567 0x6b8b4567
327b23c6 0x327b23c6
643c9869 0x643c9869
66334873 0x66334873
74b0dc51 0x74b0dc51
19495cff 0x19495cff
2ae8944a 0x2ae8944a
625558ec 0x625558ec
238e1f29 0x238e1f29
46e87ccd 0x46e87ccd
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/xxEnqs7es

Another option is to use C++20's `std::format`. However at the moment only gcc/clang on trunk (unreleased) have this feature implemented.

```cpp
#include <format>

std::string hex( uint32_t value ) {
    return std::format("0x{:x}", value);
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/roMc5ajcj